# How to configure Kismet to redetect same BSSIDs in a loop?

Tags: network, wifi, wireless, detection, kismet

So I am working on a tool to detect any wifi device using Kismet.

When I use Kismet, it works fine, but my problem is, it detects a device once, and until the MAC changes, it wont detect it again. However, I want to see, if the device is still around me and using wifi for something... I don't care if it is a access point, a cell phone or anything else, all I want is to enable kismet re-log it, even if it has the same signal strength, MAC address and name.

Basically I want Kismet to re-scan and re-log everything automatically in a loop, even if the device have been logged before. In a script I can do this maybe but I wonder if there is a easier, more stable way... Maybe a Kismet command that I missed out?

Comment: What kind of resolution do you need on the scans?   Is once every few minutes enough?  Does it have to be within seconds?

Comment: I am not really sure about how often to run them, but once every few minutes will do. I am thinking an interval longer than 5 minutes and less than 30 mins.
And regular log file would do for me.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a command for this. Your best bet is to script a scan every few minutes, or find an app which functions more like a spectrum analyzer.

Comment: yeah seems like it... but scripts just dont feel right...I can re-open the kismet and the logs but it's a little kinky..

Comment: Maybe Kismet isn't the application for the job.

Comment: I want what Kismet does... But I want it to re-detect  devices if they are still in the "zone".